# ETW EnableTrace Access Denied

Tags: c++, access-denied, etw

I want to log some events from **Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network** provider using c(c++) code in **real-time**.

When i'am trying to execute program not as Administrator, it fail at **EnableTrace** (**EnableTraceEx2**) with code 5 (ACCESS DENIED).

**BUT**

But i can Add provider to my session(if i just create and dont stop and close it in program) using ***Performance Monitor*** *without administrator privileges*.

---

Steps with perfmon:

```
//Create trace session without providers
1. StartTrace() // EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE
2. OpenTrace()  // PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME | PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD

//Wait for events
3. ProcessTrace()

//Add provider manually
4. Open perfmon and add provider manually to my session.
```

**Result:** program starts getting events!

---

Steps *without* perfmon and admin. rights:

```
//Create trace session without providers
1. StartTrace() // EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE
2. OpenTrace()  // PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME | PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD
3. EnableTraceEx2() //flag,keyword is 0, level is 0x00 or 0x04(Informational)
4. ProcessTrace()
OnError: ControlTrace() and CloseTrace() //EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_STOP
```

**Result**: fail at step 3: ACESS DENIED

1. **How i can programmatically add(enable) provider without Admin. privileges?**
2. Why perfmon can do this without elevating?

Comment: ETW tracing of kernel providers always requires admin rights. Some inbox tools auto elevate in Win7, so you may not see that the perfmon is running with admin rights